# HQL doesn't work in subquery and in-clause

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

have 3 tables in mysql like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tstudent(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
  grade int   NOT NULL,
  sex VARCHAR(1)      NOT NULL,
  birthday DATE,
  dayorboarding VARCHAR(1)    NOT NULL,
  age int   ,
  house VARCHAR(20),
  mentor VARCHAR(50)
);


CREATE TABLE ttrip(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  departureday       DATE         NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE tsignup(
  id varchar(36) primary key not null,
  s_id varchar(36) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES tstudent(id), 
  t_id varchar(36) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES ttrip(id),
  departuretransport   VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
  returntransport    VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
  remark TEXT
);
```

I am able to use this sql to query information like this:

```
mysql> select * from tsignup where t_id in (select id from ttrip where  name like '%bar%');
... ignore data ...  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when use hql like this, it doesn't work:

```
@Override
public DataGrid datagrid(Signup signup) {
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

    String hql = "from Tsignup t";  
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    hql = addWhere(signup, hql, params);

    String totalHql = "select count(*) " + hql; 
    hql = addOrder(signup, hql);
    List<Tsignup> l = signupDao.find(hql, params, signup.getPage(), signup.getRows());
    List<Signup> nl = new ArrayList<Signup>();
    changeModel(l, nl);
    dg.setTotal(signupDao.count(totalHql, params));
    dg.setRows(nl);
    return dg;
}

private String addWhere(Signup signup, String hql, Map<String, Object> params) {

    if(signup !=null){
        hql += " where 1=1 ";
        if(signup.getName() != null  && !signup.getName().trim().equals("")){
            hql += " and t.id in (select trip.id from ttrip as trip where trip.name like :name)";
            params.put("name", "%%" + signup.getName().trim() + "%%");
        }

    }
// logger will print:
    logger.info(signup.getName());
    logger.info(hql);

    return hql;
}
```

System prints like this:

```
[cz.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl]bar
[cz.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl]from Tsignup t where 1=1  and t.id in (select trip.id from ttrip as trip where trip.name like :name)
```

wondering what's the right way to make the same sql in Hql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution:

```
    String hql = "from Tsignup t";      
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    hql = addWhere(signup, hql, params);
```

...

```
        hql += " where 1=1 ";
        if(signup.getName() != null  && !signup.getName().trim().equals("")){
            hql += " and t.ttrip.id in (select id from Ttrip where name like :name)";
            params.put("name", "%%" + signup.getName().trim() + "%%");
```